# How to project an image using a reference image in java?

Tags: java, android, image

I am doing a project and would like to recreate a version of the image without noise. For example, this is the [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6blRD.jpg) image and I would like to produce an image that only displays the badminton court lines and net. This is the code that I wrote for it: `

```
  public SimplePicture findBC()
  { 
    Pixel[][] pixels = img_.getPixels2D();
    SimplePicture result = new SimplePicture(img_.getWidth(), img_.getHeight());

    int w = img_.getWidth();
    int h = img_.getHeight();
    boolean bird = false;
    boolean line = false;

    for(int r = 0; r < h; r++)       
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < w; c++)
        {      
            int ori = (pixels[r][c].getRed() + pixels[r][c].getGreen() + pixels[r][c].getBlue())/3;

            if(pixels[r][c].getRed() >= 200 && pixels[r][c].getGreen() >= 200 && pixels[r][c].getBlue() <= 100)
                bird = true;
            else
                bird = false;

            if(ori > 195 || ori < 30)
                line = true; 
            else
                line = false;

            if(line == true)
            {
                Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
                result.setBasicPixel(c, r, black.getRGB());
            }
            else if(bird==true) 
            {
                Color birdie = new Color(255, 255, 0);
                result.setBasicPixel(c, r, birdie.getRGB());
            }                
            else if(!bird && !line)
            {
                Color grey = new Color(240, 240, 240, 0);
                result.setBasicPixel(c, r, grey.getRGB());
            }                    
        }            
    }
    return result;
}`
```

However, when I tested the code, it [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjq9j.jpg) in image that is noisy from glares and the lines further away are faded. If I know what the court should look like, how do I code that to let the computer know to look for key parts and recreate a cleaner version of the image? Please and thank you :)